# Security Error in WSS 3.0

Tags: central-administration

I don't know what I did but when I click on the Job Definitions link in Central Admin I get a Security Error.

I ran the Configuration Wizard and get this.

```
02/15/2012 11:20:29  6  ERR                Failed to register SharePoint services.
An exception of type System.Security.SecurityException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Security error.
System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.GetInstance(XmlNode xml, Guid classId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Guid parentId, Guid type, String name, SPObjectStatus status, Byte[] versionBuffer, String xml)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(SqlDataReader dr)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.RefreshCache(Int64 currentVersionOverride, List`1& newObjects, List`1& deletedObjects, Int64& newestObjectVersion)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.RefreshCache()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.PutObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean ensure)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.Update()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstance.Update()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance.Update()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

I look in the Log file and see this

Exception in RefreshCache. Exception message :Security error.
02/15/2012 11:09:18.40  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0360)                    0x0570 Windows SharePoint Services    Timer                          5utx Unexpected The timer service could not initialize its configuration, please check the configuration database.  Will retry later.

Please help

Comment: Is this a new installation of SharePoint or an existing one that just started failing?

Comment: This is an existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Found this blog post mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/… Went into SP DB and searched for timer job I created & tried to uninstall and deleted the records in the object table. Now job definition page comes up again

Answer (score 1):

You might want to verify that the account that the Timer job (OWSTIMER.EXE) is running as has not expired or been disabled

Comment: It is running under the NETWORK SERVICE account and the WSS Timer Service is running

Comment: Is the config database on the local machine?

Comment: yes.It is using the Windows Internal Database (SSEE)

Comment: When you ran the Config Wizard, were you running it under your own account or the farm service account?

Comment: My own account. I am an admin on the server

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean you have all of the permissions needed in SharePoint.  In most cases, it does, but not always.  The Config DB is a perfect example as that is never accessed directly by any user - except when a user tries to run the config wizard.  Log on as the farm account and try the config wizard again.

Comment: Fixed! Found this blog post http://mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/sppersistedobject-%e2%80%93-once-deployed-%e2%80%93-do-not-change-it/

Went into SP DB and searched for timer job I created & tried to uninstall and deleted the records in the object table. 

Now job definition page comes up again